# add class to change position background image within div without javaScript

Tags: css

I can not for the life of me figure out what seems so simple. And on top of that, I have this simple css problem which I can not figure out.  :-)

**I am trying to shift the position of a background image by changing the class.** This does not have to happen within a single html file, and so **javaScript is not involved.**

This is like the classic "cropped toggle button" where the `hover` state moves the image a set number of pixels. However, it does not seem to work in this case.

In step1.html, my html looks like this:

```
<div id="progress" class="progress1">
    <p>STEP 1/3&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

In step2.html, my html looks like this:

```
<div id="progress" class="progress2">
    <p>STEP 2/3&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

Note the sole change is `class="progress1"` to `class="progress2"`.

My css looks like this:

```
#progress{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px 0px  no-repeat  !important;
    width:565px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
    margin:1em 0;
}
.progress1{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px 0px  no-repeat  !important;
}
.progress2{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -36px  no-repeat  !important;
}
.progress3a{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -72px  no-repeat  !important;
}
.progress3b{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -108px  no-repeat  !important;
}
```

I have also tried add the full `background` declaration in the id, and only changing the position in the classes, like so: `background-position: 65px -108px`.

Comment: did you consider applying background-size also? to have more control

Comment: ah I see, specifity issue .. ID more specific than class ... remove the important from the first CSS declaration

Comment: The post cited in the duplicate marking has some information that is certainly related and interesting; but it does not answer my question. It's not misleading, but it's certainly roundabout. The problem is merely a misuse of selectors, which August identified in his answer. I'm marking that as the correct answer.

Comment: A duplicate question doesn't need to answer your question ... explaining the issue is sometimes better than giviing a *non explained* answer ... what you will learn if you simply get the working code without understanding the *why*? nothing ... you will get back again here in the future with a similar issue and related to the same thing.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I certainly agree, and I'm not here to be lazy. I did read the question you linked, and while it provided information germane to my question, it didn't address the bad selector that I was using. I searched SO high and low for a related answer, and I think that there is a reason that the specificity question was not found.

Comment: so in this case maybe you didn't understand the question ... because ID is more specific than Class so it will always win == this is your issue ... If you get this then you have a plenty of workaround (remove the first important, use only classes and no ID, append ID to the class selector, etc etc etc)

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's simply that the specificity link provided as a duplicate is not a duplicate: it is an excellent reference on the generalities of css specificity, but it at no point addresses what I was doing in practise. Anyway. I'd rather not start anything like a battle over it. That's not what SO is for. (And I do agree that August's answer should have included a "why" and not just a sample of fixed code.)

Comment: It's not a battle but you need to understand that a duplicate question is not for addressing *your* particular issue but to address a more generic issue because if it wans't the case we won't have any duplicate because each question is very specific to each person ... Your issue is a specifity issue and the duplicate question already deal with such issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#progress{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px 0px  no-repeat  !important;
    width:565px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
    margin:1em 0;
}
#progress.progress1{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px 0px  no-repeat  !important;
}
#progress.progress2{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -36px  no-repeat  !important;
}
#progress.progress3a{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -72px  no-repeat  !important;
}
#progress.progress3b{
    background: url(../images/progressBar.png) 65px -108px  no-repeat  !important;
}
```

The problem was that `#progress` selector was always higher specificity than `.progress1` or `.progress2` selector even with !important. So you need to keep the specificity on same "level" to be able to overwrite it with `.progress1` or `.progress2`

Comment: Works! Thank you for identifying my bad selector. Temani's comment about the `!important` qualifier is also very noteworthy.

Comment: I agree, that's why I flagged his comment as helpful and I edited my answer to include the reason.